# The binary additive divisor problem in arithmetic progressions

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, divisors-multiples

I find quite a few results about the binary additive divisor problem, that is evaluating

\[ \sum _{n\leq x}d(n)d(n+h)\]

for certain ranges of $h$.

Are there any known results about the same count restricted to arithmetic progressions?  Straightforward googling didn't give me an answer, so I thought I'd ask here.

Any comments about the difficulties or straightforwardness of restricting to arithmetic progressions would also be just as helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if there is anything written down anywhere. However, you can write the condition $n \equiv a \pmod{q}$ in terms of a sum over Dirichlet characters $\chi \pmod{q}$, and then replace $\chi(n) d(n)$ with $d_{\chi,\chi}(n) = \sum_{ab = n} \chi(a) \chi(b)$. Now the proof of the spectral decomposition of this sum, as in work of Motohashi, should go through in the same way (albeit with a major amount of work).

Comment: The key point is that $d(n)$ is the $n$-th Hecke eigenvalue of $\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\right|_{s = 1/2} E(z,s)$, where $E(z,s)$ denotes the real analytic Eisenstein series for $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$. Similarly $d_{\chi,\chi}(n)$ is the $n$-th Hecke eigenvalue of a real analytic Eisenstein series of trivial central character and level $q^2$.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Would you mind giving a reference for the work of Motohashi?

Comment: https://doi.org/10.24033/asens.1700

Comment: @PeterHumphries those are helpful comments, thanks! :)